# Curator connection priority / preference

Tags: apache-curator

Is there a way to configure Curator to have some "preferred" or priority ZooKeeper hosts to connect?

We have two datacenters and 3 ZooKeeper nodes on each datacenter, that is all part of the same ZooKeeper cluster (6 nodes in total).

We would like to have a way to set the Curator client of each datacenter to preferably connect to the local ZooKeeper servers, not the ZooKeepers from the other datacenter.

Please, is there a way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Curator, itself, does not handle the connection. That is handled by the underlying ZooKeeper instance. You can pass whatever servers you want in the connection string. If you only want local servers, just use those. It looks like ZooKeeper added some support for what you want with ZOOKEEPER-1172. However, Curator doesn't currently support this (note: I'm the main author of Curator). Please open an Issue on Curator's Jira to support ZOOKEEPER-1172.

Update: actually, Curator *does* support it indirectly. You can use Curator's ZookeeperFactory to set the HostProvider.